# How can I create a database schema dynamically using Entity Framework in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

Basically, I have on DBContext on my App, but my App will be multi-tenant which means we need to create a separate database for each of our clients to isolate data from each other.

I found this example to create DB on Azure
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/How-to-create-a-Azure-SQL-5157ce03

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
      { 

          SqlManagementClient client = new SqlManagementClient(getCredentials()); 
     //Server Name is your SQL Azure DataBase server name, for example:da0dt6hrt6 
          client.Databases.Create("{Server-Name}", new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql.Models.DatabaseCreateParameters() 
          { 
              Name = "OnecodeTest", 
              MaximumDatabaseSizeInGB = 1, 
              CollationName = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", 
              Edition="Web" 
          }); 

          Console.ReadLine(); 
      }
```

However, what I don't know is how to create my CODE FIRST model into that new database programmatically.

this is my appdatacontext

```
public class AppDataContext : DbContext
    {

        public AppDataContext() : base("AppDataContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Module> Modulos { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Entidad> Entidades { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Propiedad> Propiedades { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ModulosPorUsuario> ModulosPorUsuario { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PerUserWebCache> PerUserCacheList { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello @Esteben V, with your reputation you should know how important it is to provide exact isse statement, code to reproduce, concrete error with stack trace and what you have tried to solve the question. Otherwise, as stated, your question falls into the Close Off-Topic category: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I dont agree with you I already pasted the code I have which are pieces of the solution, however I dont know how to connect those 2 pieces together and its not an off topic quesiton.

Comment: You don't include what you have tried to find solution yourself and where did you fail... 
Besides, before tagging Azure, have really put a minimal effort to make the work with On-Premises SQL Server (SQL Express, or Developer Edition). And if so - what exact error you get when you tried with Azure SQL DB ?

Comment: @EstebanV, you should also consider https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-documentation-map/ for managing a scale-out application.

Comment: plus one  for the link, very complete documentation.

Comment: @LuisValencia how did you go about doing this then? bcz I have a similar scenario - mine is a mult-tenant system with each tenant having their own DB, i need to create a new DB when the tenant signsup